# How can I move files to another folder with java?

Tags: java, file

I want to move files (images) from a folder to another:

For example:

> /home/folder1/image.png

to

> /home/folder1/folder2/image.png

And obviously remove the image from the folder1

I've trying to do it by reading the path and then modifying it, or using renameTo, but i can't do it.

I hope someone can help me a little with this, Thanks.

EDIT:

Well I can put the code but it's simple to explain what i did:

I just created a Folder class that has a File object of my folder (/home/folder1) , i read all the images inside and save it in an File array, then i scan it and try to change the path of every image file String to another

EDIT:

Thanks to all for the help, all are good examples, I was able to change my files to another location, there was a bunch of files I wanted to move so, I didn't want to create too many objects.

Comment: can you please add the error you obtain?

Comment: And the code you've used for that.

Comment: Easily done with Apache FileUtils `moveFile` method: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you tried renameTo and it didn't work, but this worked for me. After I renamed it I deleted the original file.

```
File a = new File("C:\\folderA\\A.txt");
a.renameTo(new File("C:\\folderB\\" + a.getName()));
a.delete();
```

Comment: renameTo has a limitation to same physical disk. so moving between disk will fail.

Answer (score 4):

In java 8+ you can simply use [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) from nio:

```
try {
    Path source = Paths.get("/home/folder1/image.png");
    Path dest = Paths.get("/home/folder1/folder2/image.png");
    Files.move(source, dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

The paths can even come from different file system providers (ie a ZipFileSystem).

Answer (score 3):

Commons-io has a few methods in the FileUtils class that can help you.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html

Example:
FileUtils.moveFile(src, dest);

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach to solving this is copying the file and then deleting it from the original location, but you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/) for more information. Also, the platform(linux, windows, is not important).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't run this, but it should work

```
File f1 = new File("/home/folder1/image.png");
File f2 = new File("/home/folder1/folder2/image.png");

f1.renameTo(f2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches for you to do that. 
This snippet is one of them, you can move your files like this way:

```
try {
    final File myFile = new File("C:\\folder1\\myfile.txt");
    if(myFile.renameTo(new File("C:\\folder2\\" + myFile.getName()))) {
        System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```