# null returned when trying to move file to overwrite another file

Tags: java

I'm trying to move *myJar.jar* from the update folder *F:\Test Server\plugins\update* to *F:\Test Server\plugins*.

I believe I'm messing up with the paths.
I have tried:

```
new File(PluginManager.class.getProtectionDomain()
                     .getCodeSource()
                     .getLocation()
                     .getPath()); 
                     //F:\Test%20Server\plugins\myPlugin.jar (just a test)

new File("update" + File.separator).listFiles(); //this however just produces null

File file = new File(PluginManager.class.getProtectionDomain()
                     .getCodeSource()
                     .getLocation()
                     .getPath()); //this gets the path where current running jar is

File[] directories = new File(String.valueOf(file))
                       .listFiles(File::isDirectory);

if (directories != null) {
    for (File dir : directories)
        System.out.println(dir.toString());
    }
}
//this also produces null - I got this code from the internet
```

Finally, I've tried:

```
File theFile = new File("F:\\Test%20Server\\plugins\\update\\myJar.jar");
if (!(theFile.exists())) { //this is always the result
    System.out.println("not found myJar.jar");
} else {
    try {
        Files.move(Paths.get("/update/myJar.jar"), 
                   Paths.get("myJar.jar"), 
                   StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I expected that it would actually not keep saying "not found myJar.jar" but alas I think I'm doing a rookie mistake.

Comment: Why are you using %20 as space? A "normal" space is perfectly valid in a Path.

Comment: In general it is not wise to hard-code paths that way. You should not rely on '\' being the path separator or similar. use the `new File(File parent, String child)` constructor to build the file instead, much more resilient. Or hand in the file name from a config or user input.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out how to do this;

```
File a = new File("F:\\Test-Server\\plugins\\update\\myJar.jar");
    a.renameTo(new File("F:\\Test-Server\\plugins\\" + a.getName()));
    a.delete();
```

[src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931444/how-can-i-move-files-to-another-folder-with-java)

Comment: You could have kept the space. Files.move is a better approach since Java 7, imho